# Category Permission Validation with REST API on Magento 2.4.4-p1 (EE)

Tags: addtocart, rest-api, magento2.4.4, magento2-enterprise

We are facing an issue with the "Category Permission" feature. Category Permission validation is not working with REST API. Below are the details:
We are facing this issue at the Adobe Commerce 2.4.5-p1 & 2.4.4-p1

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Enable Category permission from "Stores >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Catalog >> Category Permissions" with "Yes for everyone" option to allow categories, add to cart etc . Because this feature is not enaled by default.
2. Go to any of the product and assign that product into a particular Category
3. Go to that category and restrict all customer group.
4. Now use following Rest APIs to add that product for restricted customer groups:

   - POST: /rest/V1/integration/customer/token
   - GET: /rest/V1/carts/mine
   - POST: /rest/V1/carts/mine/items

Expected Result: The product should not be added to the cart for the customer because it is restricted.

Actual Result: The product added to the cart for the restricted customer and the customer is able to place the order with the restricted product.

Thanks in Advance